# How to let the user set the table size in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

i want the user to enter the number of rows in a HTML table, how do i do that? this is where is stopped.

```
var x = prompt("how many rows?");
for ( var count=1)
document.writeln(<tr>)
count++;
{
if (count==x)
break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is incomplete and moreover a mess. You wrote for statement without curly braces and the curly braces you put, it way after where it supposed to be.

If you wish to create a row inside a document, at least you need to create a html table first. (You can also do this using JavaScript)

```
<table>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can move onto the JS part where user will be asked for input.

Here is a full example.

```js
var x = prompt("how many rows?");
let count = 1;
let table = document.querySelector("table");


for (count = 1; count <= x; count++) {

 // insert a row
  var row = table.insertRow(0);

 // create two cell
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

 // default text if you want
  cell1.innerHTML = "Cell 1"
  cell2.innerHTML = "Cell 2";
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would it be better to create a HTML string in the for loop and then insert the string into the table, this way your only manipulating the DOM once rather than on every iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your response! here what i came up with:

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<title>Table</title>




</head>



<body>

<table border="1">


<tbody>

<tr>
<td>Num</td>
<td>Square</td>
<td>Cube</td>
</tr>

<script language = "javascript">


var x = window.prompt("number Of Rows");

for(var z=1;z < x;z++){

document.writeln("<tr><td>"+ z +"</td><td>"+ z*z +"</td><td>"+ z*z*z +"</td></tr>")
}


</script>

</tbody>

</table>

</body>

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple like this:

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('#input-el');
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('#button-el');
const divEl = document.querySelector('#table-display');

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const rowQty = inputEl.value;
  let html = `<table id="tableEl-${rowQty}" border="1">`;
  for (let i = 0; i < rowQty; i++) {
    html += `<tr><td>${i+1}</td><td>Row ${i + 1}</td></tr>`;
  }
  html += `</table>`;
  divEl.innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<label id="label-el" for="input-el">Number of rows</label>
<input id="input-el" type="text" />
<input id="button-el" type="button" value="Create table" />
<div id="table-display"></div>
```